# A smart way to sync development and remote repos with FTP-access only?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, git, ftp, synchronization

I'm developing a WordPress website at a host that supports FTP and MySQL access only. I'm using Git for version control and PHPloy to deploy changes from development to production. This all works fine, but since I can't set up git on the remote server, I have to manually copy the production database to update the local one. I believe certain premium WordPress plugins do it for you.

I know the FTP setup isn't to brag about, but for the time being, are there any tips on how to make the syncing less time-consuming?

Comment: What about this? https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp

Comment: What do you want to sync? Database? Because it seems that your source code is all ready in sync.

Comment: Yep, I'd like to sync databases so that what's updated by editors in the production server can be pulled to my local database and if I change any values in local tables (eg. adding a widget to a page) they'll be reflected in the production server.